# org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

Tags: maven, selenium

I get following exception on `mvn clean run` after updating `selenium-java` from `3.13` to `3.14`

```
org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:139)
at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:98)
at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:186)
at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:131)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.Utility.makeJavaClass(Utility.java:467)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.UnwovenClassFile.getJavaClass(UnwovenClassFile.java:68)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addClassFile(BcelWeaver.java:453)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.addJarFile(BcelWeaver.java:400)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.initBcelWorld(AjBuildManager.java:896)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:249)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:185)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.doCommand(AjdtCommand.java:114)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.runCommand(AjdtCommand.java:60)
at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.run(Main.java:371)
at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.runMain(Main.java:248)
at org.codehaus.mojo.aspectj.AbstractAjcCompiler.execute(AbstractAjcCompiler.java:537)
at com.browserstack.automate.mojo.AutomateBaseMojo.execute(AutomateBaseMojo.java:114)
at com.browserstack.automate.mojo.AutomateTestCompileMojo.execute(AutomateTestCompileMojo.java:19)
at
```

I can yet run run test using testng runner.

Comment: Have u changed from java 7 to 8? This looks like error with lower version of aspectj  which has issue with java 8.

Comment: Not of late, change from java 7 to 8 happened months ago

Answer (score 2):

updating aspectj dependencies in maven helped me resolve this issue

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```